# Combining answers a good thing?

Tags: discussion, answers

Can/do/should we incorporate one or more answers into our own?

Is there value in combining two or more answers into one? See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224556/reversal-of-blacklisting/224563?noredirect=1#comment479125_224563), where I think the best answer includes two answers combined with mine. I started to ask one other person if we should do so, but I can't figure out what's best to do.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. OP is *asking what to do*, not proposing an unwanted approach. It seems to me that's a perfectly legitimate question here, and notwithstanding the strength of @Andrew's "definitely Not A Good Thing", I see nothing at all wrong in including excerpts from multiple previous answers (accredited, with links) if the sum total of the answer is better suited to the relevant question than any of the cited sources.

Comment: @F You've been here long enough to know that Meta downvotes are an indication that "I don't agree with this idea".

Comment: If he's been here long enough to know, then the implication is that he's intellectually impaired... Or, just that being a mod is stressful sometimes? :) Hopefully, I haven't been here long enough to know, and it just looks like people are saying I shouldn't have asked.

Comment: No, not that you shouldn't have asked, because every idea is worth considering, even if only to be ultimately rejected. I wouldn't worry about a net couple of downvotes.

Comment: @JimReynolds It's a good question, just the positive answer "Yes, combine" is not liked by more people.

Answer (score 6):

No, combining answers is definitely Not A Good Thing.

The Stack Exchange format encourages unique answers to questions, each of which may be voted upon and from which the OP chooses the answer best for their needs.

Combining answers makes this primary aim impossible; and where the different answers come from different people it completely subverts the reputation system.

It can even be argued that where answers are sufficiently similar that combination might be a possibility, it's actually essential that they remain separate in order that different nuances can be isolated.

Comment: What's the best practice when I see one or more great but partial answers to a question? Suppose the existing answer or answers are excellent--relevant factually, maybe researched with examples or citations, and well-written--but missing another fact that seems vital or very useful. Do we want "In addition to Xxxx's points, I would add that...."? (Supposing that on a particular question, I didn't care so much as to who gets reputation points, but only what seems to best serve the OP and interested others.) I can see the problems you pointed out, and I don't know that there's a good answer.

Comment: Add that missing nugget as a comment to the good answer.

Comment: OK. That's useful. Thanks.